# Destroyed (boot/recovery).img after rebooting the device

Tags: rooting, twrp, boot, 9.0-pie, magisk

I use Realme 3 pro device with SD710 running android 9.0 with ColorOs UI, and i'm trying to root my device with Magisk module. First i followed the instructions at [link](https://www.getdroidtips.com/how-to-unlock-bootloader-on-realme-3-and-3-pro/) to unlock bootloader,then followed this [link](https://www.getdroidtips.com/twrp-recovery-realme-3-pro/) to install TWRP recovery for flashing Magisk to root my device, but after that the device cannot boot-up and i have this message on screen :[image] 
 i tried these solutions to overpass this message :

- Disable verity-check using ADB with command `./fastboot - disabled-verity - vbmeta flash-verification-enabled vbmeta.img` but i get error `fastboot: usage: unknown command -` .
- Disable verity-check by flashing a zip from this [link](https://www.androidinfotech.com/no-verity-opt-encrypt-versions/).
- Try to patch stock boot.img by using Magisk manger followed the instructions [link](https://www.getdroidtips.com/root-realme-3-pro/).

noticed: Secure boot status still `yes` in fastboot mode, and the device only boot-up iff after flashing the stock `boot.img` and stock `recovert.img` but with no root.
So i think the problem caused by secure boot, how to solve it? and if there is another one what could it be?

Thanks for advance.

Comment: patch your recovery.img with Magisk Manager on any working phone (no root required). flash the magisk_patched.img to your recovery partition. This should by-pass dm-verity

Comment: https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html#magisk-in-recovery

Comment: "If you are patching a recovery image, manually check Recovery Mode in Advanced Settings" https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html#boot-image-patching

Comment: After trying this solution, i have the same problem

Comment: then flash VBMETA from this thread https://forum.xda-developers.com/realme-3-pro/how-to/guide-unlock-bootloader-install-twrp-t3938845

Comment: I have tried this solution and i got an error as i mentioned below the picture in my question

Comment: what is output of `fastboot --disable-verity --disable-verification flash vbmeta vbmeta.img`

Comment: Here is: `fastboot: usage: unknown command - `

Comment: update your fastboot to latest version https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads (and check your commands for typos)

Answer (score 1):

Install the stock recovery first through fastboot. Then install twrp recovery again through fastboot. Then install the zip file of the stock rom. It worked for me. Get the stock recovery and stock rom from 
https://forum.xda-developers.com/realme-3-pro/how-to/guide-to-stock-rom-stock-recovery-t3940604